# Simple HTML DOM Parser & Web Browser returns different HTML

Tags: php, mysql, screen-scraping, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I am using [PHP Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to parse a webpage.

**Problem:** However, the HTML content scrapped seems to be different from the one I get if I were to use my web browser. What may have caused the difference and how can I get the same content using Simple HTML Dom as the content displayed by the web browser?

**PHP**

```
public function action_asos() {

    include_once('/home/mysite/public_html/application/libraries/simple_html_dom.php');

    $category_url = 'http://www.asos.com/Men/T-Shirts-Vests/Cat/pgecategory.aspx?cid=7616#parentID=-1&pge=0&pgeSize=100&sort=1';

    $html = file_get_html($category_url);

    foreach($html->find('html') as $content) {
        echo $content;
    }

}
```

**Actual page:**

`http://www.asos.com/Men/T-Shirts-Vests/Cat/pgecategory.aspx?cid=7616#parentID=-1&pge=0&pgeSize=100&sort=1`

**Retrieved using Simple HTML DOM**

[image]

Comment: What is the difference in content you are retrieving? You may be getting different HTML due to a user-agent difference. Also, shouldn't the '#' in the URL be replaced with an '&'? That doesn't appear to be something that should be a fragment.

Comment: Added a screenshot of the HTML retrieved using PHP. I'm not sure why there's a `#` in the URL, maybe its being used by a Javascript router.

Comment: Dump it, it's useless when making a call server-side.

Comment: I tried the URL without the `#`, still loads what I want on browser, but PHP retrieves the same HTML as before :(

Comment: Sniff the HTTP request that's actually being sent on your server.

Comment: I'd go with Fiddler, personally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide a user-agent. The lack of a user-agent is, for whatever reason, causing the server to choke.